# Cargar archivos pesados en Angular 200mb+

Tags: angular, base64, fileupload

Estoy intentando cargar un archivo pesado a traves de angular 8, el objetivo es tomar el contenido de este archivo y entregarselo al servicio en formato base64. Cuando cargo un archivo de poco peso (15mb o 20mb), me funciona perfecto, pero cuando intento cargar uno que pesa 200mb no me da ningun resultado.

Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente de la manera:

```js
let fl = new FileReader();
let data;
let databs;
fl.readAsText(this.file);

fl.onLoad = e =>{
  data = fl.result;
  databs = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)));
  
}
```

Gracias.